# How to count rows not values in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group DataFrame by some field like

```
student_data.groupby(['passed'])
```

and then count number of rows inside each group.

I know how to count values like

```
student_data.groupby(['passed'])['passed'].count()
```

or

```
student_data.groupby(['passed']).agg({'passed': 'count'})
```

but this will [exclude empties by default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html). I would like to count all rows in groups?

I found I can count rows in entire DataFrame with

```
len(student_data.index)
```

but can't find any `index` field in `GroupBy` object or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with parameter `dropna=False`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

student_data = pd.DataFrame({'passed':[1,1,2,2,2,np.nan,np.nan]})
print(student_data)
   passed
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     NaN
6     NaN

print (student_data['passed'].value_counts(dropna=False))
 2.0    3
 1.0    2
NaN     2
Name: passed, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [groupby.aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) method to compute some function on each group:

```
student_data.groupby("passed").aggregate(len)
```